# Simple linux console text editor wanted

Tags: linux

I'm a linux newbie coming from a Windows background and I am trying to find a simple full-screen console-based plain-text editor. Something that emulates the look and feel of the Windows edit.com would be perfect.

[image: windows edit.com]

Specifically, I'm looking for;

- A plain text editor.
- Console-based not GUI-based.
- Full-screen not command line.
- Menus to tell me what my options are. I don't want to have to find out and remember a complex set of keystrokes specific to that one application.
- An application that is in the default apt-get / yum repositories, or failing that is easy for a newbie to install.

I'm using small-footprint versions of Ubuntu 904 and Centos 5.5.

edit:

I suppose what I'm looking for is a console editor that conforms to the normal keystrokes used by GUI editors, ie. cursor keys to move up/down/left/right, pg-up / pg-down keys to move up and down a page, home / end keys to move to the start or end of a line etc etc. In other words, the keys we all use without thinking, in any GUI environment, be it Windows or Linux.

Comment: Should be migrated to superuser

Comment: Unix.SE would be better than Super User in some sense, but there is not migration target pointed that way.

Comment: It's certainly not programming though. It should go to SU for now, and once a migration target is available it may be appropriate to migrate to unix.SE...

Comment: I didn't know about superuser.com. Can this question be moved to there?

Comment: If you want terminal-based Sublime like text editor with mouse support, go for [Micro][1] or [Slap][2]. 

However, if you are looking for a modal text editor, look no further than [Kakoune][3].



  [1]: https://micro-editor.github.io
  [2]: https://github.com/slap-editor/slap
  [3]: https://kakoune.org/why-kakoune/why-kakoune.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the "GUI-shortcuts", try **Diakonos** editor (it is in the repositories). One of the author's goals is actually to provide similar keyboard-shortcuts interface, so that ^O, ^S, ^W, F1 etc do exactly what you would expect from a GUI editor.

Another good choice is **jed** (also in the repositories). It has emacs-like shortcuts, but it also has a menu row, allowing to visually navigate through commands (and the menu also does show the shortcuts). Jed also has some nice features for programmers. Overall, I like jed more than diakonos - give it a try.

It is also worth mentioning that almost always keyboard shortcuts are configurable. That is still an inconvenience (esp. when working with multiple PCs), but an option.

Comment: Thank you for the info, `jed` seems to be just great! The top menu is very close to the DOS edit program!

Answer (score 16):

### mcedit

@mpapis I got mcedit going and learned a lot in the process. For the benefit of other linux newbies I would like to share what I learned.

This is how I installed mcedit on my system which is a Centos 5.5 minimum build running in a VPS.

[image: mcedit screenshot]

**Starting mcedit**

To start mcedit from a console, do;

```
mcedit
```

If mcedit is installed it will start and your screen will look like the screenshot above. But if you get an error message like;

```
No such file or directory
```

then you need to install mcedit.

**Installing mcedit**

mcedit is part of a package called mc. To install mcedit you must install mc. To install mc do;

```
apt-get install mc
```

If apt-get knows about mc, then you will be asked a question like;

```
After this operation, 17.4MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Go ahead and install it by pressing the 'y' key then then the 'enter' key.

But if you get an error message like;

```
 Package mc has no installation candidate
```

then apt-get doesn't know about mc, so you have to tell apt-get about mc. mc is stored in the *universe* repository. To tell apt-get about mc, you need to tell apt-get where the *universe* repository is. The *universe* repository is a popular and safe ubuntu repository.

**Tell apt-get about the universe repository**

The /etc/apt/sources.list file tells apt-get what repositories are where. You can view sources.list by doing;

```
more /etc/apt/sources.list
```

For apt-get to know about the universe repository, the sources.list file must contain the line;

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty universe
```

Add the above line to the sources.list file by doing;

```
echo deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty universe >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

The ">>" means append the preceding text to the specified file.

To check whether the above has worked, show sources.list by doing;

```
more /etc/apt/sources.list
```

If it worked, the last line of the file will be;

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty universe
```

Now tell apt-get about the change you just made to the sources.list file by doing;

```
apt-get update
```

You should see;

```
Reading package lists... Done
```

So you can now do;

```
apt-get install mc
```

Then run mcedit by doing;

```
mcedit
```

And you should see the screenshot above.

Comment: You should be able to do it with: yum install mc

Answer (score 9):

`pico` or `nano` should do fine - `joe` is also pretty straight forward. `vi/vim` and `emacs` have somewhat of a learning curve, but both are worth the invested time.

Comment: this editors are quite simple, but not as windows user would expect

Comment: nano ought to be close - it's not menu-based per se, but all the important shortcuts are shown at the bottom of the screen by default

Comment: `joe` is also a modeless editor that someone used to `edit.com` should be able to pick up.

Comment: The problem is selection marking with Shift-Cursor and Ctrl-X/Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V 
Still waiting for an editor doing it right.

Answer (score 6):

I'm a big fan of `mcedit` it is shipped with Midnight Commander a Total Commander like file manager, additionally in the package you get `mcview` for viewing files with multiple options.

Comment: +1 BTW `mc` is a *Norton Commander* clone, since it is not a GUI application...